# How to aggregate data for logic and show non-aggregated results in the output?

Tags: sql, aggregate, presto

I have a table that looks like below:

| person | fruit | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | apple | xxxx |
| B | banana | xxxx |
| C | apple | xxxx |
| A | banana | xxxx |
| C | apple | xxxx |
| B | banana | xxxx |

I am interested in persons who have more than one banana in the data set. In this case, it would be person B. I understand how to achieve this by aggregating the data. However, if I want my result to be NOT agrregated and look something like below, what would be the best way?

| person | fruit | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | banana | xxxx |
| B | banana | xxxx |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) in subquery (in this case with [`count_if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#count_if) aggregate function) and filtering the result:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(person, fruit, date) AS (
    VALUES ('A',    'apple' ,'xxxx'),
    ('B',   'banana'    ,'xxxx'),
    ('C',   'apple' ,'xxxx'),
    ('A',   'banana'    ,'xxxx'),
    ('C',   'apple' ,'xxxx'),
    ('B',   'banana'    ,'xxxx')
)

-- query
select person, fruit, date
from (select *,
          count_if(fruit = 'banana') over(partition by person) banana_count
      from dataset)
where banana_count > 1
```

Output:

| person | fruit | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | banana | xxxx |
| B | banana | xxxx |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function such as `SUM() OVER ()` along with a conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT person, fruit, date
  FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE
                     WHEN fruit = 'banana' THEN
                          1
                     END) OVER( PARTITION BY person ) AS cnt
          FROM t) tt
 WHERE cnt > 1
```